# How to generate HTML report while using Nightwatch with Mocha

Tags: mocha.js, nightwatch.js

I'm using Nightwatch JS to run my e2e tests with the Mocha runner.
I want to integrate an HTML reporter that with the suite.

I'm trying to use the `nightwatch-html-reporter` package. But as far as I understand there is a problem with the CLI commands (it's written in the Nightwatch docs that `--reporter` will not work when using mocha).

I also copied the code sample from `nightwatch-html-reporter` to my globals.js but it doesn't seem to work either.

The tests run but there is no output anywhere.

Here is my folder structure:

```
project
  src
    spec
      e2e
        globals
          globals.js
        tests
          smoke
            testFile.js
nightwatch.conf.js
```

Here is my conf file:

```
const seleniumServer = require('selenium-server-standalone-jar');
const chromeDriver = require('chromedriver');

module.exports = {
  src_folders: ['src/spec/e2e/tests'],
  output_folder: 'report',
  page_objects_path: [
    'src/spec/e2e/pageObjects'
  ],
  globals_path: 'src/spec/e2e/globals/globals.js',
  custom_commands_path: 'src/spec/e2e/customCommands',

  selenium: {
    start_process: true,
    server_path: seleniumServer.path,
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 4444,
    cli_args: {
      'webdriver.chrome.driver': chromeDriver.path
    }
  },

  test_runner: {
    type: 'mocha',
    options: {
      ui: 'bdd',
      reporter: 'list'
    }
  },

  test_settings: {
    default: {
      launch_url: 'http://URL',
      silent: true,
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true,
        chromeOptions: {
          args: [
            "--no-sandbox",
            "start-fullscreen"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

And here is my `global.js` file:

```
var HtmlReporter = require('nightwatch-html-reporter');
var reporter = new HtmlReporter({
    openBrowser: true,
    reportsDirectory: __dirname + '/reports'
});
module.exports = {
    reporter: reporter.fn
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will work with nightwatch-html-reporter as it is probably not a mocha reporter (but correct me if I'm wrong).

You want to use built in or custom mocha reporters when using nightwatch with mocha.
You can use a custom mocha html reporter like *mochawesome* but you'll have to hack around a bit and I offer no guarantees as I only tested those hacks lightly.

Here are the instructions to use *mochawesome* 
(tested with
"mocha": "^5.2.0",
"mochawesome": "^3.1.1",
"nightwatch": "^0.9.21")

1. npm install mochawesome
2. Modify mochawesome node_modules\mochawesome *.js files to require mocha-nightwatch instead of mocha. (See instructions/explanations towards the end of the answer)
3. Presuming you're using a nightwatch.conf.js, configure your test runner to the equivalent of

   `test_runner : {
       type : "mocha",
       options : {
         ui : "bdd",
         reporter : require("mochawesome") // Please observe that you can pass a custom report constructor function here, not just reporter names
       }
   }`
4. Run tests and observe that you still see the default console reporter (spec) but that at the end of the run you also see an output like:

> [mochawesome] Report HTML saved to C:\projects\myWebApp\mochawesome-report\mochawesome.html

5. Open the html report.

This solution is hackish and fragile because *nightwatch* comes with it's own version of mocha. 
When you install *nightwatch* you will see in your node_modules a mocha-nightwatch folder. This is the mocha that is being used by nightwatch.
However *mochawesome* doesn't use mocha-nightwatch. If you look at node_modules\mochawsome\dist\mochawesome.js you will see lines of code like:

```
var Base = require('mocha/lib/reporters/base');
var Spec = require('mocha/lib/reporters/spec');
```

This means is requires *mocha*, not *mocha-nightwatch*. 
Those lines should ideally be: require('mocha-nightwatch/...). 
So please change them in all *.js files that need fixing. 
You could also fork *mochawesome* and make them like that ;)

Debugging notes: 
Try putting some additional console.logs in node_modules\mocha-nightwatch\lib\mocha.js in the Mocha.prototype.reporter function. That's how I figured out what's going on.

Answer (score -5):

If you use Mocha you can always go with mochawsome: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mochawesome 
I haven't tried it myself but it looks pretty neat.